# How to get a pattern into a written text via CSS?

Tags: css, css-sprites

some days ago I saw a website where a written text had a background-image in.

Is it already possible with CSS to get a background-image into a text?

I do not want a background-image behind the text. I have no idea to achieve this. :(

Thanks gago!

http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/232/examplewf.png

Comment: get a background-image into a text? what do you mean?

Comment: I think he wants the text to go around (probably either side of) the image, rather than having it as a background image and the text going over the top of it.

Comment: It could be a custom font too.

Answer (score 6):

@gago; you can use css3 `background clip` proprty.

for example 
**css:**

```
p {
   color: white;
   background: url(images/fire.jpg) no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

check this link for more http://css-tricks.com/7850-image-under-text/

Comment: I would still restrain myself from this due to bad browser support. Not only that but if i recall it right, this fails horribly in ie9.

Comment: you have to explain it's in your question at least which browser you want to support .this property support by moz & webkit browsers.

Comment: When it is not specified i usually asume that cross browser support is wanted cause it just makes sense. And if not.. then he would mention it. And im not the OP.

Comment: check your tags man you give  css3 on it

Comment: Either way, i would not use non-crossbrowser solution myself and I dont recommend them to others unless they ask for them directly. And im still not the OP.

Comment: This does not work for chrome right?

Comment: It works for both Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-background-clip` does the job

> HTML
>
> ```
>    <header>
>       <h3><span>B</span><span>Brainz:: An   Amazing Touch</span></h3>
>   </header>
> ```
>
> CSS
>
> ```
>     header span:first-child
>     {
>      font-size: 7em;
>      color: white;
>      background: url("strip.png") repeat center center;
>      background-size: 6px 6px;
>       background-clip: content-box;
>      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
>      -webkit-background-clip: text;
>     }
> ```
>
> [View result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jW6Q.png)

This method is only supported by `webkit` browsers which means you must set a `color` property and `background-clip` as content-box incase it fails in a `non-webkit` browser

Answer (score -1):

**The example image that you have Could be achieved with a font that has such a pattern in it.** For that you would need to use css @font-face or some other way of using custom fonts.

---

Aside from that I'd say that your only option is to make image of a text with a specific background/styling.